# Calculate the slope for each individual

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal data

```
ID<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
time<-c(0,12,36,0,7,23,68,0,23,0,32,45)
Age<-rnorm(12,45,9)
Sexe<-c("F","F","F","M","M","M","M","M","M","F","F","F")
biology1<-rnorm(12,12,3)
biology2<-rnorm (12,100,20)
biology3<-rnorm(12,45,9)
biology4<-rnorm(12,20,2)
Death<-c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
data<-data.frame(ID,time,Age,Sexe,biology1,biology2,biology3,biology4,Death)
```

I would like to calculate the slope (from the begining to the end of the folow-up) for each numerical variable (biology1,biology2,biology3,biology4) and for each individual irres; mainly a function to calculate the slope for each variable without retyping a new line of codes for each variable.I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` option with `lm`

```
dt[,
  lapply(
    .SD,
    function(x) coef(lm(x ~ time, data = cbind(x, dt[, "time"])))["time"]
  ), ID,
  .SDcols = patterns("^biology")
]
```

which gives results like

```
   ID    biology1    biology2      biology3     biology4
1:  1  0.07223152  0.07187708 -2.960618e-02  0.022861337
2:  2 -0.05728224  0.13207814 -2.349493e-01 -0.018541982
3:  3 -0.03925044 -0.63219541 -3.166489e-05 -0.009484951
4:  4 -0.01801599  0.04758699 -6.547484e-03 -0.004253647
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`. Here are the tricks:

1. Use `group_by` to group the data for each individual.
2. Use `summarise` to perform an action for each group.
3. Use `across` to do so for multiple columns
4. Use `starts_with` to select the appropriate columns
5. Use `list(slope = ...)` to name the columns.
6. Use `$coef` to extract the coefficients and `[2]` to get the slope rather than the intercept.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(across(starts_with("biology"),
                    list(slope = ~lm(. ~ time)$coef[2])))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     ID biology1_slope biology2_slope biology3_slope biology4_slope
  <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1     1        -0.0459         -1.61         -0.204        -0.00106
2     2         0.131          -0.553         0.0783       -0.0340 
3     3        -0.0462         -0.427        -0.402        -0.191  
4     4        -0.0524         -1.10          0.379        -0.0736
```

Comment: Nice solution with high readability! Upvoted yours!