# Calculating slope per subject ID in R

Tags: r, lm

I have a df resembling this:

```
ID   Block   LogB
705   1      0.133
705   2      0.678
705   3      0.987
707   1      0.133
707   2      0.678
707   3      0.987
```

I want to calculate the slope across Block 1, 2 and 3 for each ID number, to assess how LogB performance changed over time i.e., blocks. I believe the general format I need is:

`lm(x ~ y, data = df)`

However, how do I incorporate the grouping element correctly?

I've come across this post: [Calculate the slope for each individual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65728742/calculate-the-slope-for-each-individual)

But unfortunately I don't have the know-how to modify it to my needs. I'm just looking for a single slope column per ID.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'll likely want `ID` to be a factor (not a number), then `summary(lm(LogB ~ ID, df))` might be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps `LogB ~ Block * as.factor(ID)`, but you might want to use a mixed model instead, e.g. `lme4::lmer(LogB ~ Block + (1 + Block | ID), data = df)`.

Answer (score 1):

With slightly bigger dataset (and likely different feature types) it might look like something like this:

```r
str(iris)
#> 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#>  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#>  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#>  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#>  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

# split iris dataset by Species, 
# apply lm() on every subset and 
# exact single coefficient from each model.
iris |>
  split(~ Species) |>
  lapply(\(df) lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = df)$coefficients["Petal.Width"])
#> $setosa
#> Petal.Width 
#>   0.5464903 
#> 
#> $versicolor
#> Petal.Width 
#>    1.869325 
#> 
#> $virginica
#> Petal.Width 
#>   0.6472593
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `lme4::lmList()`. (Or `nlme::lmList()`; `nlme` is installed by default, so you wouldn't have to add any new packages. `lme4::lmList()` is *slightly* more robust than the version in `nlme`, but in most cases you won't see any differences.)

```r
library(lme4)
m <- lmList(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width | Species, data = iris)
coef(m)[, "Petal.Width"]
```

Or

```r
## 0 suppresses intercept (i.e., separate intercepts for
##  each species rather than baseline intercept + contrasts)
## `:` denotes interaction
m2 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ 0 + Species + Petal.Width:Species,
           data = iris))
c2 <- coef(m2)
c2[grepl(":", names(c2))]  ## select slope coefficients
```

These two models are slightly different: the first fits three completely separate models, the second assumes that all groups have the same residual variance.